# Add conditional logic on Jekyll looking if there's entries in a data file

Tags: jekyll, liquid, data-files

I'm making a job listing page using Jekyll and I decided to create a separate data file with the job positions available.

I'd like to add a condition where if there's no positions available (the data file is empty), a specific message would appear.

So I have a **job.html** where the listing should be displayed and the code I tried for showing the listing or message is:

```
<!-- Jobs -->
<section class="jobs">
    {% if site.data.jobs == '' %}
        <h1>No job openings right now!</h1>
    {% else %}
        {% for job in site.data.jobs %}
            <h1>{{ job.title }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ job.link }}</h2>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</section>
```

It didn't work, so I tried to hack it by only verifying if there's empty title tags, like so:

```
<!-- Jobs -->
<section class="jobs">
    {% if site.data.jobs.title == '' %}
        <h1>No job openings right now!</h1>
    {% else %}
        {% for job in site.data.jobs %}
            <h1>{{ job.title }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ job.link }}</h2>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</section>
```

Also did not work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty "jobs" data file will make `site.data.jobs` be `false`, so you can check that to display the message (`for` statement won't execute if that is the case):

```
{% unless site.data.jobs  %}
    <h1>No job openings right now!</h1>
{% endunless%}
```

If the data file doesn't exists at all, then `site.data.jobs` will be `nil` so the above code would work too.

## Other solution

Another approach can be to check the size of the `site.data.jobs` array:

```
    {% assign jobs_size = site.data.jobs | size %}
    {% if jobs_size == 0 %}
        <h1>No job openings right now!</h1>
    {% else %}
    ...
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! It works like a charm. I went with the unless statement.